# Powershell IF statement syntax issue

Tags: powershell, syntax

I am having some issues with getting a part of my script to work.

Say that `$SEMFINAL = /O=Default/OU=FIRST ADMINISTRATIVE GROUP/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=name1 name2@email.com`

```
IF ($SEMFINAL -match "name1 name2@email.com") {Set-variable -name SEMIFINAL -value "name1.name2@email.com"}
```

I have tried using set-variable and just $A = B but it isnt working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your string in single quotes:

$SEMFINAL = '/O=Default/OU=FIRST ADMINISTRATIVE GROUP/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=name1 name2@email.com'

then:

IF ($SEMFINAL -match "name1 name2@email.com") {$SEMFINAL = "name1..name2@email.com"}

Comment: Thats weird I dont see why that shouldnt work but I tested it in my ps environment and it doesnt set `$SEMFINAL` correctly but if I do `IF ($SEMFINAL -match "name1 name2@email.com") {$test = "name1..name2@email.com"}` then `$test` has the correct value

Comment: sets correctly for me - check for semifinal (instead of semfinal) typo in your code